# ES6 Modules not working in simple example. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, es6-modules

I'm having a few issues with modules and vanilla JS. Can someone explain to me why this test code doesn't render? It should render the word "message". I'm using VSCode with live server, so it should. I've tried doing it on Mac Os and Ubuntu, Chrome, Sadari and Firefox, and I get the same result.

I have an index.html, a main.mjs (running on the body of the html) and a myMod.mjs (acting as a module for main.mjs) file.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="myH1"></h1>
    <script type="module" src='main.mjs'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.mjs**

```
import x from './myMod.js';

const y = x;
document.getElementById('myH1').innerHTML = y;
```

**myMod.mjs**

```
export default x = "message";
```

**Code in VSCode:**

[image: Code in VSCode]

Comment: `export default x = "message";` causes an undeclared variable exception. You should be seeing the error message in your console. The proper syntax is `export default "message";`, or `const x = "message"; export { x as default }`.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi! You're half right. I did what you suggested and it still didn't work. Then, I changed the .mjs to .js and it worked (someone else told me to try that because .mjs is just for node). Then, just to check, I undid the change you had suggested, and it stopped working again. So, the conclusion is: both the declaration and changing the extension were needed. Thanks a lot, that was great help!

Comment: Ah, right, I missed that. The browser doesn't care what file extension you use, but if the url ends in `myMod.mjs` you must also `import … from './myMod.mjs';`. You should've gotten a big fat error [in your console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) about that, though

Comment: The browser does. But maybe your server refuses to serve `.mjs` files? Or at least, doesn't serve them with the correct content type?

Comment: That's right, the browser doesn't care whether it's .js or .mjs.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite this files

main.mjs

```
import { x } from './myMod.mjs';

const y = x;
console.log( y );
document.getElementById('myH1').innerHTML = y;
```

myMod.mjs

```
export const x = 'message';
```

Comment: Thanks @HardCoreQual !You're half right. I did what you suggested and it still didn't work. Then, I changed the .mjs to .js and it worked (someone else told me to try that because .mjs is just for node). Then, just to check, I undid the change you had suggested, and it stopped working again. So, the conclusion is: both the declaration and changing the extension were needed. Thanks a lot, that was great help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago. What solved the issue was, that when using es6 modules you have to run live-server in order to render your code correctly.You can't run JS with "type='module" directly in the browser without server.

Comment: You can run any JS code either in an inline script or load it as an external resource. Doesn't matter whether it's a script or module. For both types, the external resource obviously needs to be served by a server.